# backbone securityissues

Tags: backbone.js

What are the possible security risks one may face while developing a backbone app.Can someone tell me the best practices to mitigate such risks.

as in the router any users can find out the services being called

Comment: The risks are the same as any other web app (or client/server app for that matter). There's nothing specific to Backbone.

Answer (score 6):

The secret to securing a Backbone app, or any other client, is that you don't rely on client-side validation.  Be sure to validate on the server.

For example, if you were building a banking app, you wouldn't use Backbone to transfer $100 between a user's accounts and then send back to the server the new account balances as model updates.  You would instead send to the server the user's intent to transfer $100 and let the server send back the new balances.  This way the server can safely determine the user's authorization to make such a transfer between accounts, determine if sufficient funds exist, etc..

Client-side validation is nice to help reduce round-trips and give immediate feedback to the user, but it shouldn't be thought of as a method for securing an app.  E.g. Validate the format of an email address or the strength of a password on the client before sending it to the server (where it should be validated again server-side) is a good example of client-side validation.

As for web services, there are different ways to protect them.  You can use HTTPS or token-based authentication just for example.

Answer (score 5):

Another issue might be that you expose too much data. For example: don't return a full user record (to populate your models) but instead only return the data actually required for your application.

I've seen examples where (hashed) passwords were sent to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Something to consider when you are securing a backbone app is the access to the app itself.

Build an authentication page where the user enter his login/password then if the authentication is verified, set a cokkie session ID.

For example if you have a main view rendered on http://mydomain.com/app, you have to secure the access to the "/app" by using a cookies validation.

Example if your back-end is nodejs :

```
app.get('/app', function(req, res, next){
  if(!loggedIn(req,res))
    sendError(res);
  else
    next();
});
```

what loggedIn will fo is basically check if you have a sessionID in your cookies.  If yes it will allow you to access your app otherwise an "unauthorised access" message will be prompted to the user.

As mentioned earlier, client side validation is important but you have to re-enforce it by using server side validation.

HTTPS for the web services is also important.